# Encrypted Password Stores in Database But Apparently Wrong?

Tags: php, authentication, encryption

I created a simple login using a tutorial that used md5 to encrypt in the tutorial, instead of md5 I used password_hash,

```
$password = password_hash("$password_1", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

it works and stores the encrypted password in my database but when I try logging in with the non-encrypted password I get "enter username or password", the code I'm using is below - only I removed my server info:

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
// receive all input values from the form
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
$password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
$password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

// form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
// by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
}

// first check the database to make sure 
// a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR 
email='$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($user) { // if user exists
if ($user['username'] === $username) {
  array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
}

if ($user['email'] === $email) {
  array_push($errors, "email already exists");
}
}

// Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
if (count($errors) == 0) {
$password = password_hash("$password_1", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);//encrypt the 
password before saving in the database
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
          VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
header('location: testlogin.php');
 }
}

// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
}
if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
}

if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND 
 password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: testlogin.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
 }

?>
```

Is there something I need to include to get password_hash working?

Comment: the key basic thing: `password_hash` is used when you save the user the first time. then you use `password_verify` when you login

Comment: so in your login block, select first if username or email exists, if exists, fetch that row, put the password column and use `password_verify(<input password>, <hashed password from db>)` to check if user input has the correct password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When verifying the user's password, you need to use the `password_verify` function. I've adapted your login code below:

```php
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('Location: testlogin.php');
            die();
        }
    }

    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
}
```

Comment: you're a legend, thanks heaps for putting it into the code! works perfectly.

Comment: Had to wait 2 minutes before i could accept for some reason